# I programmatically created a TextView in TableLayout, it automatically sets the height and width

Tags: android, android-layout

I programmatically created a TextView in TableLayout, it automatically sets the height and width.
Can I change the height and width of the TextView manually inside the TableLayout?

Comment: Of course, the same way you should do on any other layout.

Comment: you can do it using layout params

Comment: thaks @ - Nanoc & @ - Karan Mer

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
        params.height = HEIGHT;
        params.width = WIDTH;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

same for other parameters like margin, padding etc

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   LayoutParams lParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
   lParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
```

Comment: You'd rather explain why your answer would solve his problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height and width programmatically using the following code.

```
    TableRow.LayoutParams param = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
            paramColumn1.height = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            paramColumn1.width = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

textView1.setLayoutParams(param);
```

You can also set other properties using this way.